# Why ADB Error occurred after upgrading to Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, adb

I was using Android Studio 3.6 (On Windows 10) and as Android Studio 4.0 rollout, I upgrade it.

Now I am getting a problem when I want to start emulating devices.

> Unable to Locate and

Thought the emulating device fire up, but can install the debug app there anyway.

I looked for the platform-tools directory, I feel everything is fine there. I even uninstall and reinstall the platform-tools. I have uninstalled and reinstall android studio 4.0. I also try around some suggestions for the older version of Android Studio and the ADB problem, but without success yet!

I don't know this happens in Android 4.0 alone! Any suggestions and help will be appreciated.

[image]

I had solved it now. I uninstalled the emulator and reinstall it, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworkers had this problem. After several hours of debugging, we found out that there are duplicate and conflicting environment variable for ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, ANDROID_PATH and ANDROID_HOME after updating to 4.0. The problem solved by changing those value to the same one in Android Studio at File -> Project Structure.

For reference, here are my env variable

[image: Environtment Variable]

Comment: In Windows, I cannot see these environment variables set at all.